# How can I join cells with a vertical line?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I join two selected cells with a vertical line?

If the cells F6 and F11 were the ones to join,
[image: cells to join]

one might type

```
=LINEJOIN(F6,F11)
```

and get a centered vertical line running from the middle of the bottom edge of F6 down to the middle of the top edge of F11.
[image: joined cells]

This is for a family tree project.

Comment: Excel may not be the best tool for the job. Have you considered using Visio or a similar tool instead?

Comment: You could start by recording a macro to get an idea of the requisite code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments, I tried recording a macro, but just got this:Sub linejoin()
'
' linejoin Macro
'

'
    Range("M16").Select
End Sub

Comment: Also, the cells to join could be any number of rows apart, so the line would have a variable length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out

```vb
Function LineJoin(rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range)
    Dim shp As Shape, nm As String, ws As Worksheet
    Dim st, sl, et, el
    
    Set ws = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet ' `ThisCell` = the cell with the formula
    'a [unique] name for the line
    nm = rngStart.Address(False, False) & "_" & rngEnd.Address(False, False)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Shapes(nm).Delete  'remove any already-added line
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'calculate start/end left & top
    sl = rngStart.Left + (rngStart.Width / 2)
    st = rngStart.Top + rngStart.Height
    el = rngEnd.Left + (rngEnd.Width / 2)
    et = rngEnd.Top
    
    Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, sl, st, el, et)
    shp.Name = nm  'name the line
    LineJoin = nm  'return the name of the added line
End Function
```

Comment: I'm very surprised that a UDF can create a shape. Cute.

Comment: @BigBen - me too, but I guess the risk of a UDF doing that is low, since it's unlikely to mess up the calculation tree?

Answer (score 1):

Every cell has an individual `Top`, `Left`, `Height` and `Width` property.

With these you can define the line's start and end coordinates.

Create a `Shape` object with the command `Shapes.AddLine` with the calculated coordinates.

And that's all. You get a line.

Here is an example. You can define a userbutton which start the macro.
Select the two cells, and start the macro.

```
Sub drawline()

If Selection.Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub
Set cell1 = Selection.Areas(1)
Set cell2 = Selection.Areas(2)
If cell1.Row < cell2.Row Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine cell1.Left + cell1.Width / 2, cell1.Top + cell1.Height, cell2.Left + cell2.Width / 2, cell2.Top
ElseIf cell1.Row > cell2.Row Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine cell2.Left + cell2.Width / 2, cell2.Top + cell2.Height, cell1.Left + cell1.Width / 2, cell1.Top
ElseIf cell1.Column < cell2.Column Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine cell1.Left + cell1.Width, cell1.Top + cell1.Height / 2, cell2.Left, cell2.Top + cell2.Height / 2
Else
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine cell2.Left + cell2.Width, cell2.Top + cell2.Height / 2, cell1.Left + cell1.Width, cell1.Top + cell1.Height / 2

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure how to do this - where would I input the command "Shapes.Addline"?

Comment: @mike62 Add the sample code to my answer, pls. try it.